# Simplest way to adjust background color of a react-toastify Toast

Tags: css, reactjs, toast

I tried it like this but it doesn't do anything:

```
const myToast = () => (
  <div style={{backgroundColor: myColors.green}}>
    ...some text content...
  </div>
)
```

Then in App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  showMyToast = () => {
          toast(<MyToast />, {
            closeOnClick: false,
            toastId: 'my_toast',
            autoClose: true,
            closeButton: false,
            position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
            className: 'toast'
          })          
  }
}
```

I'm seeing a white toast with my text on it.

Comment: changing background color based on toast type can be done using the `theme` property. Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71193722/6816568)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on @Laurens answer I found the pattern in the code sandbox very useful. Here's what I did to get the notification shown below

[image]

First, I mounted my toast container at the root of my App, inside my `App` component

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import store from './redux/store';
import Routes from './Routes';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ToastContainer
        autoClose={2000}
        position="top-center"
        className="toast-container"
        toastClassName="dark-toast"
      />
      <Routes />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Then, for each notification style, I defined a series of CSS styles. The components looked like so

```js
// customToast.js
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { css } from 'glamor';

const customToast = {
  success(msg, options = {}) {
    return toast.success(msg, {
      ...options,
      className: 'toast-success-container toast-success-container-after',
      progressClassName: css({
        background: '#34A853',
      }),
    });
  },
  error(msg, options = {}) {
    return toast.error(msg, {
      ...options,
      className: 'toast-error-container toast-error-container-after',
      progressClassName: css({
        background: '#EE0022',
      }),
    });
  },
  info(msg, options = {}) {
    return toast.info(msg, {
      ...options,
      className: 'toast-info-container toast-info-container-after',
      progressClassName: css({
        background: '#07F',
      }),
    });
  },
};


export default customToast;
```

To use these just do `import customToast from 'customToast.js'`. Now you can use `customToast.success`, `customToast.error` etc

The style for the success notification is shown below

```css
.toast-success-container {
  color: #000 !important;
  border-radius: 8px !important;
  background: #FFFFFF !important;
  border: 1px solid #34A853 !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(248, 175, 175, 0.1) !important;
}

.toast-success-container-after {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.toast-success-container-after::after{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 7px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #34A853;
}
```

You'll also notice that I had to stick a series of `!important`s in my css

Comment: How did you import your overridden success/info/error functions into your App? Something like "import { success, error, info } from "./unity-cockpit-toasts.jsx";"? Calling them after import doesn't work for me. Thanks.

Comment: Worked it out. I just needed to import the default functions into an object: "import Toasting from "./toasts.jsx";"

Comment: There was a mistake in info custom info Toast...
You have written `return toast.error`
but there we have to write `return toast.info` for info Toast otherwise, this info Toast will show in red colour.

Comment: Just found small mistake in  "info(msg, options = {}) { ...."  . toast method should be "info" but its "error"

Answer (score 20):

**Easiest Solution**

The easiest solution to adjust the BG of Toastify, or in fact any styles would be to use the ToastContainer props toastStyle: which takes in JSX attributes.
After importing the necessary packages , while adding the ToastContainer component , just pass in the toastStyle prop and you shall be good to go.

```html
<ToastContainer toastStyle={{ backgroundColor: "crimson" }} />
```

Answer (score 13):

The easiest solution is setting the `theme` property, as mentioned in [the docs](https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/migration-v8/#clear-separation-between-type-and-theme).
You can:

**Set theme globally**

```js
//Set the theme globally 
<ToastContainer theme="colored" />
```

**Or define per toast**

```js
// define per toast
toast.info("Display a blue notification of type info", { theme: "colored" });
```

This changes the background color based on the toast type (`error`, `warning`, `info` etc).
Hopefully this helps anyone in future.

Comment: An underrated answer, yet the easiest and the absolute best, straight out of the documentation!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Glamor](https://github.com/threepointone/glamor) for easily adjusting simple things like toast background color.
[This example](https://codesandbox.io/s/q8035lx169) displays a simple toast with a green background using glamor.

```
toast("Hello!", {
    className: css({
        background: "#00FF00 !important"
    })
});
```

If the requirements are more complex you can implement your own styles globally as per [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/xo22y152nz).

Comment: 404 on the exampler

Answer (score 3):

What about (for version 9.1.1):

```
toast.info(msg, {
  position: 'top-right',
  autoClose: 15000,
  hideProgressBar: false,
  closeOnClick: true,
  pauseOnHover: true,
  draggable: true,
  progress: 0,
  progressStyle: { background: '#E8DFD0' },
  theme: 'colored',
  style: { background: '#766852' },
});
```

};

Answer (score 2):

You can simply override it in CSS if the color is a hardcoded value. However, you could also use [Helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) if the color needs to be variable e.g. as an app theme color that can change through user preferences or something. Looking at your example, you would include

```
<Helmet
    style={[
      {
        cssText: `
          .Toastify__toast--success {
            background: ${customColor} !important;
          }
      `,
      },
    ]}
  />
```

The `customColor` variable would be pulled out of your store and could be updated on the fly, giving you a custom toast background color.

I think this is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

1.install glamorous using following link https://glamorous.rocks/basics/#installation

2.after that import css to your js file like this..

```
import { css } from 'glamor';
```

3.after that give your own style to the toast popup like this..

```
 toast.configure({
            autoClose:10000,
            draggable: true,
            hideProgressBar: true,
            position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
              toastClassName: css({
                fontSize: '18px !important',
                backgroundColor: '#da1c36 !important',
                padding: '15px !important'
              }),
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You can set a predefined className on each toast

```js
toast.info("Display a blue notification of type info", { className: 'bg-warning' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Dwaipayan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15923000/dwaipayan-chakroborty)'s answer,

You can use CSS styles in your `ToastContainer` using the `toastStyle` tag.
What worked for me was to use my CSS variables for the `backgroundColor` as well as the `color` property.

```
<ToastContainer toastStyle={{backgroundColor: 'var(--background)', color: 'var(--foreground)'}}/>
```

The variables can be changed in your Global CSS file according to user's device theme:

```
:root {
    --background: #ffffff;
    --foreground: #000000;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    :root {
        --background: #000000;
        --foreground: #ffffff;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me:

```
import { toast, ToastContainer, Slide } from 'react-toastify';
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

const Msg = ({ closeToast, toastProps }) => (
  <div>
    <h5>Toaster banner title {toastProps.position}</h5>
    Description This is the description part you can add your content here.
  </div>
);

function Example() {
  const notify = () => {
    toast(<Msg/>, {style:{ background: '#fff2df'}});
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={notify}>Notify</button>
      <ToastContainer transition={Slide} autoClose={false} style={{ height: "100px", width: "500px" }} />
    </>
  );
 }

export default Example;
```

Answer (score -2):

- **If you want change the without CSS. 
  notify = () => this.toastId = toast.error('error') { error: "error", info: "info", success: "success", warning: "warning", } Use like this Above 
  OtherWise .

  ### Toastify__toast--error{ background-color: red; }**